# trying to deploy 5 nodes on virtual

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to install hadoop on 5 nodes with virtual box . I have been through many websites 
any of them did not work properly. And I used this website "http://blog.gopivotal.com/pivotal/products/in-45-min-set-up-hadoop-pivotal-hd-on-a-multi-vm-cluster-run-test-data" . I was struck in the middle. I'm unable to use the command tar -xzf . can any one please help me how to install CDH on 5 nodes with virtual box?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I'nk Cloudera distribution would a good choice for you. For beginners it is very easy to use. Cloudera express installer is available for automated installation.

Have a look at the following URL for installation steps :

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html